# How to prevent TestNG from skipping tests?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testng

We have a number of tests, many of them have shared spring context, but generally we have a few of them specific for given tests. When due to some changes some context fails to load TestNG skips all tests starting from this point. The problem is it is not only skipping given test file, or tests for given spring context, it skips all further tests, and we have to fix one in order to know which ones has to be checked yet.

Any ideas how to prevent TestNG from skipping whole suite when only few files has failed while setting context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring initialization happens in @Before... methods, so parameter:

`-configfailurepolicy skip|continue` should helps.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted. Tests in current files are still skipped, and testNg is going right to the next test file. Thanks a lot.